# Does Linux; Does Windows 10? XP? DOS? auto write-to/modify a second drive when connected/mounted?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, ssd, disk-utility

Have HDDs in vintage computers, and in PVRs etc. And use/have Mac/Linux/Windows machines.

On occasion would like to use various drive utilities or SMART reporting tools only available to me on one OS, on drives of an alien OS - and would prefer they not be written to or otherwise modified (except by the drive tool).

Know Mac OS will immediately write Spotlight and Trash type files onto a connected drive.

Does Linux? Does Windows 10, or on a vintage PC Windows XP? Or (doubt it) DOS (say on a SeaTools DOS CD)?

Ex 1. Say want to use smartmontools Linux to test a PVR HDD. Boot into Linux with the PVR drive connected (SATA). Any modifications?

Ex 2. Say want to use WD Data Lifeguard/Dashboard on a PC system. Boot into Windows with a Mac or Linux system drive also connected (SATA or PATA->SATA). Any modifications?

(And certainly comprehensive backup is better than drive tools/utilities.)

Thanks.

Comment: Linux should not try to write to a drive unless a filesystem (in a partition) is mounted.  You would want to make sure that automatic mounting is not enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As suggested, checked that for this distro the default is to only auto-mount external drives.